# How to find out what process wrote a particular log in dmesg?

Tags: dmesg

I have bought an android tv box which has an hdmi capture card inside. From time to time the capture card stops to record. I need to restart the device for it to work again. I am trying to find a way to 'reset' the card with some commands, eg by restaring a service.

The problem is that i can't find what service or process to restart. I havs taken a look at kernel logs with dmesg.

I can see lines like initialiase pcm capture when i start a recording. But how can i find out what process or service actually 'triggered' the kernel log??